# Terraform elastic beanstalk

Tags: terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Can any one guide me, how to set alerts(SES) for CPU and others in with in elastic beanstalk using Terraform?
I have already setup an ROR Elastic Beanstalk stack using Terraform, now I need to setup the Cloud Watch with it. Is there any settings which comes with Elastic Beanstalk for Terraform?

Also how to setup two environments(Staging and Production) in Elastic Beanstalk using Terraform, I also need to setup Cloud Watch and email alerts. Can anyone guide me. I need this for AWS.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudwatch_metric_alarm.html

Comment: yes, I already read it, but the questions is how to use it with Elastic Beanstalk, and also please tell me how can I use the S3 bucket into the instances launched by Elastic Benastalk? Thanks for your comment.